# Listing unique elements over multiple vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, unique

I have three vectors (a, b, and c) and found the common elements in all three using

```
common<-Reduce(intersect,list(a,b,c))
```

I want to find out now which elements are unique to a. I can't use `a[!(a%in%common)]` since that could return elements in a and one other vector.

I don't think this is a new or unique question, but part of my problem in finding the answer is that I'm not sure what the `a[!(a%in%common)]` function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setdiff(a, union(b,c) )  # .....
```

Depending of course whether the meaning of "unique to a" is the same to you as it is to me, but for me it is not the same as `a[!(a%in%common)]` .

Comment: No, they are definitely not the same, hence my question. This works well, though -- thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reduce` and setdiff for an arbitrary length list

```
Reduce(setdiff, list(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be `a[!(a %in% union(b,c))]`.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm embarrassed for not thinking of this myself. It is quite simple, though there is an alternate answer that is even more simple.